# Mysql query that searches for rows that contain duplicate fields and deletes them?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table with fields like:

```
username, description, password.
```

**Sometimes, members copy the description from one-another, to save time**

So I have this:

**John - John's description - John's password**

**Michael - John's description - Michael's password**

Is there a mysql query that searches for duplicate field entries and deletes them?
How about deleting the entire row of data while we're at it?

Comment: You should not store the passwords in the database.

Comment: Entirely duplicate rows or just any duplicate field?

Comment: What if the description is intentionally the same?

Comment: Entire duplicate rows. This is what I am trying to prevent for this precise application. Intentionally duplicating the description. If deleting the rows entirely is not possible, maybe there-s a way to delete just the duplicate fields.

Comment: Let's say that two descriptions matched.  How would you know which one you wanted to delete?

Comment: Both if there is no easy solution - but idealy: I have the NOW attribute and delete the ones which were copied after the first one.

Comment: I just had an idea - AllInOne - maybe I can check if there are duplicates before inserting into the database. The problem is - if id had complete duplicates then It would be easy.

Comment: This is what unique constraints on columns are for.  If you protect columns or groups of columns with a unique constraint, then duplicate data can't be inserted in the first place.  Also, plaintext passwords in the database?  REAALLLY BAD IDEA!

Comment: About the passwords, going to change, you are right. If I add unique constraints for the columns, what happens to the duplicates already entered? I also add the data with a php while loop - does the loop brake if there is a duplicate?

Comment: Here's a query that should demonstrate the extent of the duplicates currently within your data set: SELECT description, COUNT(description) AS cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY description
HAVING (cnt > 1)

Comment: @Mark Byers, where to store passwords?

Comment: @DinuRodnitchi You should *never* store plaintext passwords anywhere. You should hash the password with a strong hash algorithm (*not* md5) that uses a random salt value that is unique to each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new table, move non-duplicate entries in it, remove the old table and rename a new one.

**Example:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `new_table` as
    SELECT * FROM `old_table` WHERE 1 GROUP BY [columns to remove duplicates by];

DROP TABLE `old_table`;

RENAME TABLE `new_table` TO `old_table`;
```

However, it's good for periodically uses only, and it doesn't check is there are any duplicates. It just groups unique entries and moves them to another table. It's useful when you want to filter your entries.

---

Another way is to check like this:

```sql
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `description` LIKE '%descriptiontexthere%'
```

Then, if some results are found, it's a duplicate.
However, there's a big disadvantage: *user can change only 1 letter and query will fail.*
That disadvantage, however, can be avoided (not fully) by splitting a description into an array. For example, split on every 100 characters and then check like in above example, but with multiple conditions (e.g. `description LIKE 'first100chars' OR description LIKE 'second100chars'`) .

---

The third way is to split a description to an array of words and then select rows with too many same words. Row with X same words could be a possible duplicate. You can set the treshold based on length of an entered description.

**You can never be sure if it's duplicate or not, unless it's completely the same entry.**

Comment: Ty very much for answering, testing the queries now.